# Spring trucantes time part from a Date GET RequestParam

Tags: spring, datetime, spring-mvc, get, http-request-parameters

I have a Spring MVC REST controller with an object as param:

```
public List<AccessResponse> getAccesses(AccessRequestParams params) throws Exception {
    log.debug("Received get request");
}
```

The param is a simple bean with some properties, I copy here just the important date property:

```
public class AccessRequestParams  {

    Date since=null;
    ...

    public SincePageFilter() {
        super();
    }

    public Date getSince() {
        return since;
    }

    public void setSince(Date since) {
        this.since = since;
    }
    
    
}
```

When I call this URL:

http://localhost:8080/v1/accesses?since=2017-05-04T12:08:56

**The `since` property is filled with 2017-05-04 00:00:00, Why it truncates the time part?**

I also tried to:

- Call this URL with space instead of "T" between date and time `http://localhost:8080/v1/accesses?since=2017-05-04%2012:08:56`
- Added @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") annotation for `Date since` property.

But I did not find any solution.

My Spring config has this BEAN:

```
@Bean
public FormattingConversionService mvcConversionService() {
    DefaultFormattingConversionService conversionService = new DefaultFormattingConversionService(false);

    DateTimeFormatterRegistrar dateTimeRegistrar = new DateTimeFormatterRegistrar();
    dateTimeRegistrar.setDateFormatter(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));
    dateTimeRegistrar.setDateTimeFormatter(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
    dateTimeRegistrar.registerFormatters(conversionService);

    DateFormatterRegistrar dateRegistrar = new DateFormatterRegistrar();
    dateRegistrar.setFormatter(new DateFormatter("yyyy-MM-dd"));
    dateRegistrar.registerFormatters(conversionService);

    return conversionService;
}
```

Comment: What Date class can you see in the imports? java.util.Date or java.sql.Date ?

Comment: java.utils, good point :-)

Comment: You set your date formatter to `yyyy-MM-dd`. I would strongly suggest to not use either `java.util.Date` or `java.sql.Date`. Instead use the new time classes from Java 8 (not so new anymore). Use `LocalDatetime` instead. If you use that you should also be able to ditch your customizations for the conversion service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have registered a global `DateFormatter` for the type `java.util.Date` with format `yyyy-MM-dd`. This works as expected.

- You can change it to include the time part.
- Or you can use a type `LocalDateTime` in your request bean. Then the other format will be valid: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` (with space).
- Or you can remove the configuration and let Spring use the default formats.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was wondering if `dateTimeRegistrar.setDateFormatter()` will apply to all Date as well as `setDateTimeFormatter()` but you're says it will be applied for different object types?.

Comment: DateTimeFormatterRegistrar is for java.time.LocalDate and java.time.LocalDateTime. DateFormatterRegistrar is for java.util.Date